# Where would you include replace occurrences in Swift for XML?

Tags: swift, xml, xcode, replace, xml-parsing

I'm trying to display a simple array. I have everything parsed, however I'd like to display the ingredients one under the other using `replacingOccurrences` the problem is I'm not sure where I would fit that in the code.

Something to the effect of:

`let newString = recipeIngredients.replacingOccurrences(of: ", ", with: "\n")`

***I'm just not sure where to include this line***

I would assume it's somewhere in the XML Parser code, but I've had no luck.

Recipes.xml

```
<dish>
    <title> Pancakes </title>
    <calories> 350 calories </calories>
    <ingredients> ing 1, ing 2, ing 3 </ingredients>
</dish>
```

XMLParse.swift

```
struct Recipes {
  var title = ""
  var calories = ""
  var ingredients = ""
}
```

RecipeTableViewController.swift

```
class RecipeTableViewController: UITableViewController, XMLParserDelegate {

@IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!

var tableViewDataSource = [Recipes]()

var thisName = ""
var recipeTitle = ""
var recipeCalories = ""
var recipeIngredients = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myTableView.dataSource = self
    myTableView.delegate = self

    if let path =  Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Recipes", withExtension: "xml") {
        if let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: path) {
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

// Table View Delegates

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return tableViewDataSource.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    let titleLabel = cell.viewWithTag(11) as! UILabel
    let caloriesLabel = cell.viewWithTag(12) as! UILabel

    titleLabel.text = tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row].title
    caloriesLabel.text = tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row].calories

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let resultsVC = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ResultsViewController") as! ResultsViewController

    // Information to be passed to ResultsViewController
    resultsVC.getTitle = tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row].title
    resultsVC.getIngredients = tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row].ingredients

    // Push to next view
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(resultsVC, animated: true)

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

// XML Parser

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
    thisName = elementName

    if elementName == "dish" {
        var recipeTitle = ""
        var recipeCalories = ""
        var recipeIngredients = ""
    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    let data = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

    if data.count != 0 {
        switch thisName
        {
            case "title": recipeTitle = data
            case "calories": recipeCalories = data
            case "ingredients": recipeIngredients = data
            default:
                break
        }
    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "dish" {
        var recipe = Recipes()
        recipe.title = recipeTitle
        recipe.calories = recipeCalories
        recipe.ingredients = recipeIngredients

        print(recipe)
        tableViewDataSource.append(recipe)
    }
}
}
```

`print(recipe)` returns: 
Recipes(title: "Pancakes", calories: "350 calories", ingredients: "ing 1, ing 2, ing 3")

I understand this could be done as an array, but I'd like to figure out this format as well. Thanks!

Comment: Your code for foundCharacters is wrong and may cause problems. See my answer to your earlier question for the proper implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my own question for anyone who needs it

```
case "ingredients":
      recipeIngredients = data
      recipeIngredients = recipeIngredients.replacingOccurrences(of: ", ", with: "\n")
```